# Noteworthy: Web Font and Its (Possible) Alternatives

Tags: font-recommendation

I am trying to use Noteworthy font (available on Mac OS X 10.7.2) for my web application. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it on [MyFonts](http://new.myfonts.com/) nor [typekit](http://typekit.com); I mentioned these two sites just because so far they have a pretty good font selection and easy to integrate. Do you  know where / how I can use this font for the web?

In case it's not possible, I am hoping that someone might have a suggestion for an alternative font that might look / feel like Noteworthy. WhatTheFont returned with a few suggestions (e.g. Nobel Cond Light, Wasabi Thin, Xeilo Condense), which unfortunately don't quite work well.

**Edit**:
To be clear, I need more help to find another font that has a similar look / feel to Noteworthy.

[image]

Comment: can you please pick an answer? thanks! @moey

Answer (score 11):

I have been looking for this also, my findings are:

> Noteworthy **is** Filmotype Brooklyn, available at Font Bros (and other font shops) for about $29
>   http://www.fontbros.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=FILM-BROO
>
> Filmotype Alice is a lighter weight:
>   http://www.fontbros.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=FILM-ALIC
>
> They are also both available in a value package:
>   http://www.fontbros.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=FILM-ALFA

Source: http://typophile.com/node/80861

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Handlee is pretty similar and it's in Google Webfonts. With Google Webfonts all you have to do is link to a page at the top of your HTML and you're good to go to use the font!

[Handlee on Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Handlee)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "custom" font support for browsers is actually almost perfect. Every browser except for old versions of IE will do it if you use @font-face and ttf/eot (and there are plenty of converters).

You can host the fonts in your server as long as they are [GNU GLP](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) or you have the webfont (you can usually buy it from the font owner). Dafont.com has lots of GNU GLP fonts, I can't really think of any similar ones right now, but it's worth a browse. A good option is to contact the creator and ask him/her directly. Another option would be to make the titles/whatever you are intending to use in the website as images. There are no legal issues there, because you own the font and you are not "distributing" it by putting it in your site.

Answer (score 2):

Not so close to Noteworthy but nice is the font Purisa.
Almost unfindable, you can see it [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Purisa.png) and [download it here](http://packages.debian.org/sid/fonts-tlwg-purisa).
It's free (open source) so you can use it for all use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A new font from wegraphics.net called [WG Legacy Edition](http://wegraphics.net/downloads/legacy-edition-a-free-handwritten-font-face/) is very close:

[image: WG Legacy Edition screenshot]

Comment: Whoa. That's a serious ripoff of Noteworthy! If Noteworthy is Helvetica (heh), this is definitely its Arial...

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble finding that font, there's one very similar to it called Anime Ace found at dafont.com

Answer (score 0):

http://photoshopextras.com/fonts/noteworthy.html

Link above worked for me!
Hope this is OK.

Comment: Hi Kev, welcome to GDSE and thank you for your contribution! Could you please explain a bit more about what you found at the link? This way, your answer is also useful to future visitors, in case the link breaks at a later time. Thanks!

Comment: Something feels fishy about this one legally...

Answer (score -2):

It's going to be hard to find an alternative - especially, when you're going to use it in a web-app.

For a web app you got to remeber, that costum font support is still very limited. Though there are possibilities with CSS (http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-on-your-website-with-css) or script to generate images from text...

In Flash it's no problem to embed a Font, but without ... I don't know any secure and reliable way to asure that the Client sees exactly what you want to show - with a costum font - but to convert text to images

Comment: Let's put aside the challenges of making a non-"standard" font to work on the web. Do you have any reference of a different font that might just look like Noteworthy?

Comment: actually, custom fonts are fairly widely supported now. What's not necessarily widely supported is quality rendering of said CSS embedded fonts.

Comment: I agree on the fairly wide support. Personaly I can't wait for CSS to work without the current restrictions.

Comment: This answer would be correct about 3 or 4 years ago, but support for web fonts is pretty universal in browsers now.  IE has had it since about IE5, as well as modern Firefox, Chrome, even Android/iOS.  Also, the rendering of it is fine - rendering issues come about by using fonts that are improperly hinted (and not testing your site on Windows, where such fonts *will* look ugly/messed up).